# Remove textbox from inside object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, fill

I am completely new to illustrator. Somehow a textbook became a part of an object in a project I am working on. How can I get rid of the textbook and then fill the object with the same brown color as the other bits? Sorry for the rudimentary question, but I can't figure it out :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the text tool to remove all the text. Then use the the direct selection tool (the white arrow - keyboard shortcut A) and select all the points in the figure. "Edit > copy", hit delete to remove the text box and then "edit > paste in place". Then pick the right colour.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your text and shape are grouped together. Double click one the shape next to the text. That will take you inside the group. Then select the text and cut it. Then get out of the group by click anywhere outside where no objects within this group. Then paste the text and take it wherever you want and you can fill the shape with the right color.